# Extracting Information Content from PowerPoint Shapes for analysis

Tags: extract

I am working on a project where I need to analyze the information content represented by shapes in PowerPoint slides. While I can extract the shapes using libraries like pptx, I struggle to capture the holistic information intended by the entire slide. Converting the slide to an image for analysis is an option, but PowerPoint slides are not typically saved as PNG or JPEG files.

I am looking for suggestions on how to effectively analyze the information content of PowerPoint shapes or slides directly. Are there any existing libraries or approaches that could assist in extracting and understanding the information conveyed by the visual elements on a PowerPoint slide?

Thank you in advance for any guidance or recommendations!